# Unable to post simple form data in HTML

Tags: php

I created simple contact me form and want to post form data to PHP page where data will be stored.

I am unable to figure out where to upload create_form.php file. Blow is my code.

```
<form name="customer-details" method="POST" onsubmit="return  formValidation() action="contact_form.php">
  <fieldset>
<legend>Personal information:</legend>
Name:*<br>
<input type="text" id="name" name="name" placeholder="Your Name"><br>
Company Name:<br>
<input type="text" id="company" name="company" placeholder="Your company Name"><br>
Email Address*:<br>
<input type="email" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Your Email Address"><br>
Interested in:<br>
<input type="text" id="interest" name="interest" placeholder="Interested in"><br>
Your query*:<br>
<textarea id="query" name="query" placeholder="Your query here(more then 10 words)..."></textarea><br>
<button id="submitBtn" name="submitBtn" type="submit">Submit Form</button>
</fieldset>
</form>
```

I saved contact_form.php file inside my themes folder. When I click on submit button, page is not found. Which is correct path to put contact_form.php file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would never create a `create-form.php`, doing so would introduce a security problem.

For example, lets say your client changed themes, this contact form would still work. Even with the theme deactivated. The same is true of any form handler, AJAX handler, or endpoint for a remote service that directly accesses a PHP file inside a theme or plugin.

WordPress is a CMS, it's supposed to handle all the requests made to it, not individual files in a plugin or theme

Instead, don't specify an action on your form, include a hidden input to check against, and then look for that input to handle your form input, e.g.:

```
// Template
<form method="POST">
    <input type="hidden" name="aviras_contact_form" value="contact_form">
    ....
</form>

// functions.php
add_action( 'init', function() {
    if ( empty( $_POST['aviras_contact_form'] ) ) {
        return;
    }
    // handle form submission
}
```

For AJAX, use `register_rest_route` ( consider asking a new question on how to do that ). For 3rd party call ins or handlers, use rewrite rules or check for parameters

Also, indent your code, all the major popular editors today all auto-indent for you and have packages to reindent and beautify automatically ( PHPStorm, Netbeans, Sublime Text, Coda, etc etc )

Comment: I followed this guide - https://www.inkthemes.com/how-you-can-easily-create-customized-form-in-wordpress/
Blogger did the same, uploaded the php file inside themes folder. Have a look.

Comment: That blogger is wrong, not everything you read online is the best way. Keep in mind that if you create your own file, you'll have to bootstrap WP which means reaching up several folders to include a file, and you still have the problem that the contact form handler will run even when the theme is deactivated

Comment: I've commented on said blog, pending approval. To be honest, from what I read, it wouldn't work anyway. The guy never tells you to create the database table, makes assumptions about where the create_form.php is located and includes no server side sanitisation. You'd be much better off ignoring it or using a plugin such as Ninja Forms ( free ) or Jetpack

Comment: exactly even including JavaScript does not work that way. I had hard time figuring out that and then added js code inside header template

Comment: the wp_enqueue_script function and hooks is what you want there :) best to ask a new question for that though

Comment: Actually I code in MERN stack. So I am JS guy. This is kind of personal project doing for my friend. I do work with MVC framework but it needs you to understand whole architecture. So I was finding a quick workaround to do this job. :)